# update and delete data from a MySQL Database table

Tags: mysql, sql-update, delete-row

I have a DB table. i want to update and delete data from that table. I am new in php and MySQL. I tried but can't work. can anybody help me, please?????
My code is bellow:

**For Update------------**

```
<table border = "1">
        <tbody>
            <caption>
                Update or Delete your event.                
            </caption>
            <tr>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>Message</th>
                <th>Update/Delete</th>
            </tr>
            <?php 
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqldata)) {
                    ?>
                <tr class="grey">
                    <td class="no">1</td>
                    <td class="message"><?php echo $row['message']; ?></td>
                    <td class="button">
                        <a href="editevent.php"><input type="button" name="update" value="Update"></a>
                        <input type="button" name="delete" value="Delete">
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="white">
                    <td class="no">2</td>
                    <td class="message"><?php echo $row['message']; ?></td>
                    <td class="button">
                        <a href="editevent.php"><input type="button" name="update" value="Update"></a>
                        <a href="delete.php"><input type="button" name="delete" value="Delete"></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            <?php
                    break 1;
            }
             ?>
        </tbody>        
    </table>
```

**For Delete:--------------**

```
<?php 

    $id = $_GET['id'];


    $delete = "DELETE FROM calendar_event WHERE id='".$id."'";

    mysql_query($con,$delete);
    mysql_close($con);

 ?>
```

Codes are not appropriate. please, anybody give me a correct code.

Comment: you need a connection. Plus, if I wanted to, and your code worked, couldn't I just keep calling your php and delete all your data?

Answer (score 2):

**YOUR WAY OF DOING THINGS IS ABSOLUTELY DREADFUL** and if you ever post this on a public site you'll wake up the next day to all your data gone, deleted by Google.

However, if you insist on doing it this way, simply add the `id` you want to the query requests:

```
 <td class="button">
     <a href="editevent.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"><input type="button" name="update" value="Update"></a>
     <a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"><input type="button" name="delete" value="Delete"></a>
 </td>
```

Comment: Not to mention I could simply navigate to `delete.php?id=';drop table calendar_event--` and delete your entire table/database. Again, absolutely dreadful.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. @Blindy

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass 'id' in query string. Replace

```
    <a href="editevent.php"><input type="button" name="update" value="Update"></a>
    <a href="delete.php"><input type="button" name="delete" value="Delete"></a>
```

with

```
    <a href="editevent.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><input type="button" name="update" value="Update"></a>
    <a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><input type="button" name="delete" value="Delete"></a>
```

assuming query is fetching id.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 mistakes I can see

1. in first tr you used button for delete instead of  tag and in second tr you used  tag was this intentional or by mistake I would suggest to use a tag instead.
2. I think the second block of code you wrote for delete:-------- is from page delete.php? Am I right if yes then it seems you are trying to get id of the record to be deleted from `$id = $_GET['id'];` but you are not passing any id in get from the previous page so all and all update your code of the first page were you are drawing the table as follows and replace  with the actual Id of your element in database

   ```
   <table border = "1">
   <tbody>
       <caption>
           Update or Delete your event.                
       </caption>
       <tr>
           <th>No</th>
           <th>Message</th>
           <th>Update/Delete</th>
       </tr>
       <?php 
           while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqldata)) {
               ?>
           <tr class="grey">
               <td class="no">1</td>
               <td class="message"><?php echo $row['message']; ?></td>
               <td class="button">
                   <a href="editevent.php?id=<?php echo <Your element Id goes here> ?>"><input type="button" name="update" value="Update"></a>
                   <a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo <Your element Id goes here> ?>"><input type="button" name="delete" value="Delete"></a>
               </td>
           </tr>

           <tr class="white">
               <td class="no">2</td>
               <td class="message"><?php echo $row['message']; ?></td>
               <td class="button">
                    <a href="editevent.php?id=<?php echo <Your element Id goes here> ?>"><input type="button" name="update" value="Update"></a>
                   <a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo <Your element Id goes here> ?>"><input type="button" name="delete" value="Delete"></a>
               </td>
           </tr>

       <?php
               break 1;
       }
        ?>
   </tbody>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$i=0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqldata)) {
    $class = ($i%2==0) ? 'white':'grey';
    ?>
    <tr class="<?php echo $class; ?>">
        <td class="no"><?php echo ($i+1); ?></td>
        <td class="message"><?php echo $row['message']; ?></td>
        <td class="button">
            <a href="editevent.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><input type="button" name="update" value="Update"></a>
            <a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><input type="button" name="delete" value="Delete"></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php $i++; } ?>
============
delete
============
<?php 

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $delete = "DELETE FROM calendar_event WHERE id='".$id."'";
    mysql_query($con,$delete);
    mysql_close($con);

 ?>
```